# Sumar valor retornado de una función en otra función

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema para sumar el resultado de una función. La cosa es que una función me da un resultado que quiero sumar en otra función, pero no encuentro la manero de hacerlo. Os dejo el código a continuación.

Lo que quiero es sumar en la última función el porcentaje y el precio con la variable r que contiene el resultado de la primera función.

```
document.querySelector('#calcular').addEventListener('click', () =>{
  const n1 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#select').value);
  const n2 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#selectDos').value);
  const n3 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#selectTres').value);

  var r;

 if(n1 == 415.35  && n2== 1 && n3 == 1){
    r = "26,70";
  }else if( n1 == 415.35  && n2== 2 && n3 == 1){
    r = "40,05" ;
  }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2==3  && n3 ==1 ){
    r = "66,75";
  }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2== 1 && n3 ==2 ){
    r ="35,60" ;
  }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2== 2 && n3 ==2 ){
    r ="53,40" ;
  }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2== 3 && n3 ==2 ){
      r ="89,00" ;
  }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2== 1 && n3 ==3 ){
    r ="53,40" ;
  }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2== 2 && n3 ==3 ){
    r ="80,10" ;
  }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2== 3 && n3 ==3 ){
    r ="133,51" ;
  }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2== 1 && n3 == 1){
      r = "21,16";
    }else if( n1 == 759.55  && n2== 2 && n3 == 1){
      r = "31,74" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2==3  && n3 ==1 ){
      r = "52,91";
    }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2== 1 && n3 ==2 ){
      r ="28,22" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2== 2 && n3 ==2 ){
      r = "42,33" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759,55  && n2== 3 && n3 ==2 ){
        r = "70,54" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2== 1 && n3 ==3 ){
      r = "42,33" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2== 2 && n3 ==3 ){
      r = "63,49" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2== 3 && n3 ==3 ){
      r = "105,81" ;
    }

    
  console.log(r)



  document.querySelector('#r').innerHTML = r;

  nuevoCalculo();
 
});







function nuevoCalculo(){

var button = document.createElement('input');
button.type = 'text';
button.id = 'porcentaje' 

var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.appendChild(button);  

var button = document.createElement('input');
button.type = 'text';
button.id = 'precio' 


var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.appendChild(button);  


var button = document.createElement('input');
button.type = 'button';
button.id = 'submit' 
button.value = 'precio';
button.className = 'btn';
button.onclick = function() { 


  const resul = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#r').value);

  const porcentaje = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#porcentaje').value);
  const precio = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#precio').value);

var resultadoFinal = resul + porcentaje + precio;







console.log(resultadoFinal);
};
var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.appendChild(button); 


}
```

Comment: Ya en la [respuesta a tu otra pregunta](/a/571763) te habían dicho _En javascript, los decimales se indican con un punto, no una coma._ (de hecho, no solo en JS...) Si `r` es lo que vas a sumar más adelante, ¿ya reemplazaste las comas por puntos?

Comment: ya esta remplazado y pasa lo mismo.

Comment: ¿Qué es "lo mismo"? Adjunta un [repro] (y si es un snippet, mejor) para reproducir el problema. Hice las pruebas (y reemplazando las comas por puntos) funcionó.

Comment: Por cierto... ¿Estás _seteando_ el value de `r` en el campo, luego de calcularlo? (antes de la llamada a `nuevoCalculo()`). No olvides depurar tu código. Es **fundamental**.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías indicar el código HTML para comprobar que elementos estas usando y si están construidos acorde al código. Porque si no, debemos dar por supuesto cosas.
La variable '`r`', no tiene un valor por defecto, por lo que si no entra en ninguno de los condicionales, terminará siendo '`undefined`'.
Al elemento con id "`r`", lo usas con un "`document.querySelector('#r').innerHTML = r;`", así que entiendo que debe ser un `div`, pero luego lo lees con un "`document.querySelector('#r').value`" así que uno de los dos es incorrecto.
El valor que le das al elemento '`#r`' sigue usando coma en vez de punto para indicar decimales, así que al hacer un `parsefload`, entiende que son dos valores distintos y solo usará el primero.
Un ejemplo del código modificado podría ser este:

```js
document.querySelector('#calcular').addEventListener('click', () =>{
    const n1 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#select').value);
    const n2 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#selectDos').value);
    const n3 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#selectTres').value);

    var r=0;

    if (n1 == 415.35 && n2== 1 && n3 == 1){
        r = "26.70";
    }else if( n1 == 415.35  && n2== 2 && n3 == 1){
        r = "40.05" ;
    }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2==3  && n3 ==1 ){
        r = "66.75";
    }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2== 1 && n3 ==2 ){
        r ="35.60" ;
    }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2== 2 && n3 ==2 ){
        r ="53.40" ;
    }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2== 3 && n3 ==2 ){
        r ="89.00" ;
    }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2== 1 && n3 ==3 ){
        r ="53.40" ;
    }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2== 2 && n3 ==3 ){
        r ="80.10" ;
    }else if(n1 == 415.35  && n2== 3 && n3 ==3 ){
        r ="133.51" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2== 1 && n3 == 1){
        r = "21.16";
    }else if( n1 == 759.55  && n2== 2 && n3 == 1){
        r = "31.74" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2==3  && n3 ==1 ){
        r = "52.91";
    }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2== 1 && n3 ==2 ){
        r ="28.22" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2== 2 && n3 ==2 ){
        r = "42.33" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759,55  && n2== 3 && n3 ==2 ){
        r = "70.54" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2== 1 && n3 ==3 ){
        r = "42.33" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2== 2 && n3 ==3 ){
        r = "63.49" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759.55  && n2== 3 && n3 ==3 ){
        r = "105.81" ;
    }

    document.querySelector('#r').value = r;
    nuevoCalculo();

});


function nuevoCalculo(){

    var button = document.createElement('input');
    button.type = 'text';
    button.id = 'porcentaje' 

    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild(button);  

    var button = document.createElement('input');
    button.type = 'text';
    button.id = 'precio' 

    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild(button);  

    var button = document.createElement('input');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.id = 'submit' 
    button.value = 'precio';
    button.className = 'btn';
    button.onclick = function() { 
        const resul = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#r').value);
        const porcentaje = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#porcentaje').value);
        const precio = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#precio').value);
        var resultadoFinal = resul + porcentaje + precio;
        container.innerHTML+="<div> Resultado: "+resultadoFinal+"</div>";
    };
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild(button); 
}
```

```html
    select 1 <input id="select"></input><br>
    select 2 <input id="selectDos"></input><br>
    select 3 <input id="selectTres""></input><br>
    <button id="calcular">Calcular</button><br><br>
    r <input id="r"></input><br>
    <div id="container"></div>
```